# radio button of the previous page unchecked when clicked the back button

Tags: java, android

why when I hit the back button on second activity, the radio button on the first activity is unchecked ?

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

p/s: this is the previous activity

```
if (keroh.isChecked()|| molek.isChecked() || tangga.isChecked() || bandar.isChecked() || bukit.isChecked() || batu.isChecked() || tanjung.isChecked() || klebang.isChecked()){

                    Intent next1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, jenis.class);
                    startActivity(next1);
                }
```

Comment: more codes , and elaborate your question

Comment: @Fatihah Could you show us some code as to how you create/launch each Activity? The standard behaviour is that the Activity will still be on the activity stack in its previous state, so this is definitely where we should look!

Comment: your explanation is pretty hard to understand. If you're using the onbackpressed by default without overriding it from the second activity, it shouldn't behave like that. But if you're opening a new intent on back pressed, that's is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you mentioning the home button, I believe that you may be confusing the 'Back' button and the 'Up' button. The 'Up' button sits at the top of the screen and should navigate the user to the hierarchical parent of the Activity (which will be listed in the Manifest). The 'Back' button that appears at the bottom, should simply pop the second Activity off the stack to reveal the first Activity underneath in its same state.